# How to define the JavaC version used by JasperReports to match Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, javac, build.xml

I've done a lot of searching and I can't find an answer. I'm working on a large Netbeans project that is set to compile JasperReports at the same time that it compiles the project. The problem is we want to set JasperReports to compile with the same version of JavaC selected in Netbeans instead of the JavaC version that is on the OS path.

I think it can be solved by modifying build.xml.

Here is what I believe is the relevant section of the file.

```
<target name="-post-compile" depends="compile-report"/>
<target name="compile-report" depends="init">
    <taskdef name="jrc" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask" classpath="${javac.classpath}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.classes.dir}/...proj/reports"/>
    <jrc tempdir="${build.classes.dir}/...proj/reports" compiler="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJavacCompiler" destdir="${build.classes.dir}/...proj/reports">
        <src>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/reports">
                <include name="**/*.jrxml"/>                    
            </fileset>
        </src>
        <classpath path="${run.classpath}"/>
    </jrc>

    <!--copy the styles into the classpath-->
    <copy todir="${build.classes.dir}/...proj/reports">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/reports">
            <include name="**/*.jrtx"/>
        </fileset>            
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="-pre-init">
    <!--Make sure javac is on the path for the jasperreports-->
    <echo>Testing that javac is on the path.</echo>
    <exec executable="javac" >
        <arg value="-version"/>
    </exec>

</target>
```

I truncated a couple file paths to be "...proj".

Comment: There seems to be some information on how to select a version [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/815778/producing-java-16-jasper-files-using-java-17-ant-build).  It involves creating a jasperreports.properties file in the classpath.